# Generating all pentominoes by cutting and pasting

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Is it possible to place the twelve pentominoes around a circle in such a way that if two of the pentominoes find themselves next to each other, it is because one of the two can be obtained from the other by cutting out one of its component squares (thus obtaining a tetramino) and glueing it elsewhere?

Comment: This question probably belongs on math.stackexchange.com and not here. In any case, NB that removing a square from an $n$-omino need not leave an $(n - 1)$-omino; in general it will leave some collection of $k_i$-ominos, with $\sum k_i = n - 1$. It is not clear to me from the wording of the question whether you mean to allow maneuvers for which the intermediate step is not an $(n - 1)$-omino; this makes a difference in whether, e.g., the $V$ and $W$ and pentominos can be adjacent in the circle (where $V$ and $W$ refer to Conway's notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino#History ).

Comment: Intermediate step must be a tetramino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Ugly representation below (* is the cell to be moved to . to obtain the next pentamino)

```
                                                                     .
####* -> ###* -> ### -> ### -> ###  -> *##  -> ##  -> ##  -> ##. -> ### ->  *   -> ####. -> #####
.        #.      #*     # .    * #.      ##     ##     #*     #      #     ###.     *
                 .      *                 .     .*     #.     #*     *      #
```

Comment: And Hexominoes?

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos, absent some special insight you answer these questions by constructing the graph where pairs of n-ominoes are joined by an edge if you can move between them in the way you describe, then looking for a Hamilton cycle.  There is lots of off the shelf software (e.g. sage) available for the second step, but you probably have to do the first step yourself.

Answer (score 5):

For pentominoes, there are 4080 inequivalent ways to do it. (Reversing the direction of a cycle doesn't count as a separate solution.) Answering the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355220/generating-all-pentominoes-by-cutting-and-pasting#comment891314_355229) to Mikhail's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/355229), here is a solution for hexominoes:
[image: cycle of hexominoes]
I verified that such cycles exist for polyominoes with up to 13 cells. I have assumed that the intermediate step must be connected, as explained in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355220/generating-all-pentominoes-by-cutting-and-pasting#comment891310_355220) to the original question. Without this requirement, there are 16800 solutions for pentominoes.

(Edit) And here is a cycle for the 108 heptominoes (I curled it up a bit to save some space):
[image]

Comment: There are now OEIS sequences [A367123](https://oeis.org/A367123) and [A367436](https://oeis.org/A367436) for the number of Hamiltonian cycles, without and with the requirement that the intermediate step must be connected, respectively.